# Rule for "/username" in HTACCESS

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to implement a `RewriteRule` in my `.htaccess` to enable the following URL structure:

```
http://example.com/([a-zA-Z\.]*) -> user.php?username=$1
```

I tried it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z\.]*)$ user.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If I go to `localhost/victorbarbu`, it will redirect to `user.php?username=victorbarbu`, but if I go to `storage/`, it will still go to `user.php`. What can I do to avoid this type of redirection?

This is my current `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+subdir/
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Comment: but if I go to `storage/` - Did you mean `localhost/storage/`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z.]*)$ user.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Change your rule regex to `^([a-zA-Z.]*)$`.